# How to execute SQL query with parameters in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, read-sql

I am using `pyscopg2` and have a method that returns a list based on a SQL query. The below works fine...

```
def checkAnalysisStartDate(self):
    session = self.connection()
    cursor = session.cursor()
    ids = self.getAnalysisIds() # this is a list of integers
    cursor.execute("select start_date from analysis_run_history where analysis_id in %s", [tuple(ids)])
    final_result = [i[0] for i in cursor.fetchall()]
```

I want to pass the same list of integers but this time return a `DataFrame` from the results.  When I try this though....

```
import pandas.io.sql as sqlio

def getAnalysisMetaStatsDF(self):
    session = self.connection()
    ids = self.getAnalysisIds() # this is a list of integers
    data = sqlio.read_sql_query("Select * from analysis_stats where analysis_id in %s", [tuple(ids)], session)
    print(data)
```

I get back...

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'cursor'
```

I think it's something with the way I am passing the parameters to `read_sql_query()` but I am not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call a function make sure that the call matches its signature.  You can look up the signature by running `help(sqlio.read_sql_query)`, typing `sqlio.read_sql_query?` in IPython or in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query).  You will find something like this:

```
Signature:
read_sql_query(
    sql,
    con,
    index_col=None,
    coerce_float: 'bool' = True,
    params=None,
    parse_dates=None,
    chunksize: 'int | None' = None,
    dtype: 'DtypeArg | None' = None,
) -> 'DataFrame | Iterator[DataFrame]'
```

Notice that the second parameter is the database connection object, not the parameters of the query.  In your case a call like the following is more appropriate:

```py
sqlio.read_sql_query(query_string, session, params = ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

engine = create_engine("mysql://root:admin@localhost/pythondb", pool_size=10, max_overflow=20)

table = pd.read_sql("select *From emp", engine)
```